# Eclipse .classpath location

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

Is there a way to specify where the .classpath file is located in an Eclipse project? By default it is at the top level of the project. Being able to change that location would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but could be wrong.  Could you expand on why you think you need to do this, and what you're trying to accomplish?  We might be able to give better suggestions.

Comment: In my particular case, CM has files at the top level locked down and it is a bureaucratic pain to make changes. I just want to be able make same local changes that will never get checked in to spike a proof-of-concept. Changing the location of the .classpath file would be an end run around the bureaucracy.

Comment: FYI it is hidden, in terminal I used `ls -al` to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I am pretty sure there is no way to change the location of this file, you could set up your project directory in a location of your choosing (which is where the .classpath file would reside) and then link all the source directories from the location where the project actually resides.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think there is no such way (other than change the source code).

Comment: How would changing the source code change where the .classpath file resides?